# Grid inside an Access form

Tags: ms-access

I was looking through some Access templates, and bumped into the Task Database.
It uses a grid inside a form, but I can't understand what component it's using:

[image: Screenshot of the Task Database - Task List form]

When I look in Design View I can only see a list of fields:

[image: Screenshot of the Task List form in Design View]

I guess this is pretty basic and sure it's covered in MSDN, but it seems I'm unable to find proper search keywords.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Format Property of the Form.

In the Property Sheet, the property *Default View* must be set on *Split Form*.

You can choose whether the datasheet is on top or below the form by changing the property *Split Form Orientation*.

You can adjust the splitter to view the datasheet only and then hide the splitter handle by changing to *No* the property *Split Form Splitter*.